# mkdir failing in c++ system call - argument of type int incompatible with parameter of type const char*

Tags: c++, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory in some c++ code based on a command line argument.

The command line argument is a number (1, 2, 3, etc) and I want to make a folder that is "Output1", "Output2", etc.  Each call of the program only gets 1 number and makes 1 folder.

In main I have:

```
string folder = "0";
if (argc == 2)
    folder = argv[1];
RunSimulation(c, 0, folder);
```

Then:

```
void RunSimulation(Combo c, int it, string folder){
    //Create a directory for the files based on the command line args
    stringstream fileName;
    fileName << "/work/jcamer7/HallSim/Output" << folder;
    system(mkdir(fileName.str().c_str()));
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *" system(mkdir(fileName.str().c_str()));
```

The parameter I am passing in is clearly a string so I am a bit confused. Am I getting the command line arg right? Not sure..

Thanks in advance.
Jenna

Comment: Have you read the [`mkdir` manual page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html)? Do you know what the function actually does? What the [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function does? Hint: The error is *not* from your `mkdir` function call.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call `system`:

```
int mode = 0222; // for example
mkdir(fileName.str().c_str(), mode); // Return-code check omitted for brevity
```

Here `mkdir` is a system call, not the string (shell command) passed to `system`.

More information can be found in `mkdir (2)` and `system(3)` man pages.

Comment: Thanks !! I had that originally and was getting an error. I switched to the system and added the sys header file. I guess that fixed the original error. Thank you very much.